# In M1 you could place a Static Block anywhere. In M2 I cannot

Tags: static-block, custom-layout-update

Adding a block using a Widget works fine -- BUT my only choices are to add the block to ALL CMS pages or to All Category pages.  I have specific blocks made for specific pages, how can I place them without writing a bunch of code (since I am not the best coder, but can follow instructions well). thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: you already have the option to insert static block to category pages from the backend only, change category display setting to display static block and products and just add your static block, also if you want to call just one static block on every category page then just overide catalog_category_view.xml in your theme/module and call that static block

Comment: Adding to main content area is easy, but how do I add a block to the left sidebar?